# Validate range alpha method

Tags: c#, range

I use `Range` method to get range of values in alphabetic I.E:

```
char.TryParse(txtFrom.Text, out char fromValue);
char.TryParse(txtTo.Text, out char toValue);

char[] alphabetRange = Enumerable.Range(fromValue, toValue - 'A' + 1)
                                 .Select(i => (Char)i)
                                 .ToArray();
```

So if `fromValue` is `B` and `toValue`  is `D`, it returns an array of `B,C,D` and this is correct.

Problem is if user use `fromValue` as `D`  and `toValue` as `B` how can I throw an exception that it can't be done?

Comment: Why not use an `if` before calling `Range`?

Comment: Like `if (fromValue>toValue) throw new Exception("Can't do that");`?

Comment: Maybe you just want to swap toValue and fromValue so that the user input is always valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not throw an *exception*, but just use an if/else that shows a message box, but to check if one character is "greater" than another just use `>`

```
if (fromValue > toValue)
{
    MessageBox.Show("'to' character must be greater than 'from' character");
}
else
{ 
    // do what you do now
}
```

You could also do things like checking for consistent casing, handling non=character inputs, etc.

I would also note that the second parameter to `Range` is the *length* of the output range, so I think you want:

```
Range(fromValue, toValue - fromValue + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could always select the `Min` and `Max` values between the two textboxes (regardless of which character is in which textbox), and then use an `OrderBy` to either order `ascending` or `descending` depending on if the `fromValue` is less than or greater than the `toValue`.

This way if the user enters `fromValue` as `D` and `toValue` as `B`, the output would be `D, C, B` (which is what I would expect as a user).

For example:

```
char.TryParse(txtFrom.Text, out char fromValue);
char.TryParse(txtTo.Text, out char toValue);

// Get the smallest and largest of the two values
var minVal = Math.Min(fromValue, toValue);
var maxVal = Math.Max(fromValue, toValue);

var alphabetRange = Enumerable.Range(minVal, maxVal - minVal + 1)
    .OrderBy(i => fromValue < toValue ? i : -i)  // If from > to, sort by the negative of i
    .Select(i => (char) i).ToArray();
```